# Use split on dataframe with POSIXlt as critera

Tags: r, split, dataframe, posixlt

I am attempting to split and summarize some data based on time.

There is some redundant info here which shouldn't interfere with this post. I want to split the data based on FiveMinBar and then get the first opening price, the max high, the min low, the last close. and the last FiveMinBar.

```
            Date  Time  Open  High   Low Close            DateTime          FiveMinBar
10173 2000-01-03 09:31 70.00 70.00 69.88 70.00 2000-01-03 09:31:00 2000-01-03 09:35:00
10174 2000-01-03 09:32 70.00 70.00 69.50 70.00 2000-01-03 09:32:00 2000-01-03 09:35:00
10175 2000-01-03 09:33 69.94 70.00 69.50 70.00 2000-01-03 09:33:00 2000-01-03 09:35:00
10176 2000-01-03 09:34 70.00 70.00 69.38 70.00 2000-01-03 09:34:00 2000-01-03 09:35:00
10177 2000-01-03 09:35 70.00 70.00 69.50 69.81 2000-01-03 09:35:00 2000-01-03 09:35:00
10178 2000-01-03 09:36 69.81 69.88 68.75 68.75 2000-01-03 09:36:00 2000-01-03 09:40:00
10179 2000-01-03 09:37 68.75 69.06 68.75 68.75 2000-01-03 09:37:00 2000-01-03 09:40:00
10180 2000-01-03 09:38 68.81 69.06 68.56 68.63 2000-01-03 09:38:00 2000-01-03 09:40:00
10181 2000-01-03 09:39 68.56 69.00 68.50 68.56 2000-01-03 09:39:00 2000-01-03 09:40:00
10182 2000-01-03 09:40 68.56 69.00 68.13 68.13 2000-01-03 09:40:00 2000-01-03 09:40:00
10183 2000-01-03 09:41 68.63 68.63 67.75 67.88 2000-01-03 09:41:00 2000-01-03 09:45:00
10184 2000-01-03 09:42 68.00 68.06 67.25 67.38 2000-01-03 09:42:00 2000-01-03 09:45:00
10185 2000-01-03 09:43 67.38 67.38 67.00 67.19 2000-01-03 09:43:00 2000-01-03 09:45:00
10186 2000-01-03 09:44 67.13 67.25 66.75 66.81 2000-01-03 09:44:00 2000-01-03 09:45:00
10187 2000-01-03 09:45 66.88 67.25 66.00 66.31 2000-01-03 09:45:00 2000-01-03 09:45:00
```

My first try was to do this using sapply with

`split(data, data$FiveMinBar)`

However, split does not work on POSIXlt data. I did come up with the below solution though it is far from "R optimal" in that it creates an empty data frame, requires coercing FiveMinBar to numeric and then converting back to POSIXlt, and uses a for loop.

My solution:

```
 results <- data.frame(Open=numeric(), High=numeric(), Low=numeric(), Close=numeric(),
                        DateTime=numeric())

  for (i in 1:length(unique(data$FiveMinBar))){
    temp <- data[data$FiveMinBar == unique(data$FiveMinBar)[i],]
    Open=temp$Open[1] 
    High=max(temp$High) 
    Low=min(temp$Low)
    Close=temp$Close[nrow(temp)]
    DateTime= as.numeric(temp$DateTime[nrow(temp)])
    results <- rbind(results, cbind(Open, High, Low, Close, DateTime))
  }

   results$DateTime <- as.POSIXlt(results$DateTime, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Which gives this result:

```
    Open  High   Low Close            DateTime
1  70.00 70.00 69.38 69.81 2000-01-03 09:35:00
2  69.81 69.88 68.13 68.13 2000-01-03 09:40:00
3  68.63 68.63 66.00 66.31 2000-01-03 09:45:00
4  66.25 66.50 65.63 65.81 2000-01-03 09:50:00
5  65.88 65.88 64.25 64.36 2000-01-03 09:55:00
6  64.31 64.38 63.25 63.44 2000-01-03 10:00:00
7  63.44 64.50 63.25 64.19 2000-01-03 10:05:00
8  64.25 64.63 63.75 64.44 2000-01-03 10:10:00
9  64.63 64.94 64.19 64.81 2000-01-03 10:15:00
10 64.88 65.25 64.56 65.13 2000-01-03 10:20:00
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I would prefer to keep the data as a data frame and not convert to xts.

Thank you.

Here is code to recreate the initial data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 
10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 10959, 
10959, 10959), class = "Date"), Time = c("09:31", "09:32", "09:33", 
"09:34", "09:35", "09:36", "09:37", "09:38", "09:39", "09:40", 
"09:41", "09:42", "09:43", "09:44", "09:45"), Open = c(70, 70, 
69.94, 70, 70, 69.81, 68.75, 68.81, 68.56, 68.56, 68.63, 68, 
67.38, 67.13, 66.88), High = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 69.88, 69.06, 
69.06, 69, 69, 68.63, 68.06, 67.38, 67.25, 67.25), Low = c(69.88, 
69.5, 69.5, 69.38, 69.5, 68.75, 68.75, 68.56, 68.5, 68.13, 67.75, 
67.25, 67, 66.75, 66), Close = c(70, 70, 70, 70, 69.81, 68.75, 
68.75, 68.63, 68.56, 68.13, 67.88, 67.38, 67.19, 66.81, 66.31
), DateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = 31:45, hour = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), mday = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), mon = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), FiveMinBar = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), hour = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), mday = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), mon = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), tzone = c("", 
"EST", "EDT"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("Date", 
"Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "DateTime", "FiveMinBar"
), row.names = 10173:10187, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really that you have a `POSIXlt` value in a data.frame. Those are stored in a list and since data.frames are lists you have a list of lists which isn't super easy to work with. If you want to store date/times values in a data.frame, you a better off using the sibling data type `POSIXct`. This is stored as a simple vector rather than a list.

In the above example, you can covert the column with

```
data$FiveMinBar <- as.POSIXct(data$FiveMinBar)
```

and then split should work without a problem

```
split(data, data$FiveMinBar)
```